# Forgotten Mattermost password. Not getting reset emails

Tags: user-account

I recently spring cleaned my lastpass account (a little too thoroughly).

And have lost my mattermost password.

I've tried to request new password but the notifications aren't getting through.

Anyone know who I can contact to get this resolved?

Cheers

Craig

Comment: Password reset sent (by email).

Comment: Thank you.

Have responded.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I pinged bgm for you so expect it will be resolved shortly

Comment: Thanks Pete,

Matthieu's emailed me overnight.

Comment: then pls Accept the answer

Answer (score 0):

I am having problems registering with you. Chris Burgess suggested that I advise you here. The email has never been sent to me to confirm for "foreclosurepedia".

Thank you!

IN RE:  [CiviCRM 5.9.1 Cannot Read Database Information](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/28136/civicrm-5-9-1-cannot-read-database-information)

Comment: Email sent, with new password. For other folks running into the same issue, you can email me at mathieu@civicrm.org.

Comment: We are emailing now. Thanks! The issue continues that the initial email to verify is not being sent to me. Thanks!